# Wordpress : Unable to save or update posts with Emoji

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, emoji

I host my WordPress (v5.4.2) blog on 000webhost.com and I am unable to save any post with emoji characters. I get this error `Updating failed. Could not update post in the database`

I have tried changing these lines in wp-config.php

```
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4' );

define( 'DB_COLLATE', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' );
```

I also migrated all my tables in MySQL to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` with the below step.
[image]

But none of these worked, what I am missing? Please help
My WordPress version: 5.4.2

`wp_encode_emoji()`

Comment: I have the very same issue and tried all the first steps as having the right DB charset and collate. 
Moreover, it happened one day I haven't changed anything, which is strange and let me think it could be triggered by WordPress Crons..

Answer (score 10):

Adding this code in functions.php fixed it for me:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', function( $data, $postarr ) {
if ( ! empty( $data['post_content'] ) ) {
    $data['post_content'] = wp_encode_emoji( $data['post_content'] );
}
return $data;
}, 99, 2 );
```

Comment: This helped me when I added it to the end of the `functions.php` of the current theme using the Theme File Editor.

Comment: I also had to include 'post_title' such as:
`$data['post_title'] = wp_encode_emoji( $data['post_title'] );`